# How to realize "posedge asynchronous reset logic" in verilog?

Tags: verilog, fpga, intel-fpga

i know high level async reset can be achieved like:

```
always@(posedge clk or posedge rst)
begin
  if (rst==1)
```

but how to realize posedge async reset, which means the moment reset edge coming up, the logic in **always block** reset immediately?

i wrote the logic below:

```
always@(posedge clk or posedge rst)
begin
  rst_pre<=rst;
  if(!rst_pre && rst) // to test if rst is posedge
      //execute reset logic here...
```

but the question is, the **always block** was triggered in a unexpected high frequency, i finally figured out that although there was **only 1 posedge of rst**, the always block was triggered by rst signal much more than 1 time.
(tested using altera cyclone 10LP with quartus 18)

I think the method i used to achieve posedge async reset is not stable, can anyone tell me what can i do to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to achieve is a asynchronous reset. It can be `posedge` or `negedge`.

```
always@(posedge clk or posedge rst)
begin
   if (rst) 
      // do the reset
   else begin
      // your normal execution logic
   end
end
```

If you want to use `negedge` reset then you can use:

```
always@(posedge clk or negedge rst)
begin
   if (~rst) 
      // do the reset
   else begin
      // your normal execution logic
   end
end
```

Other than that, there is nothing complicated on reset. Both on these occasions, on `posedge`/`negedge` of `rst`, block will get triggered and it will do the reset.

Comment: thanks，what i want to achieve is reset my logic immediately after posedge of rst coming. But not reset my logic at the next posedge of clk.

Comment: Yes, that's what asynchronous reset means. If you see, in the sensitivity list we have posedge rst. That will make you procedural block to be executed when there's a posedge   of the rst signal.

Comment: there's one question about the logic you showed. if the rst signal stay high for a long time, my logic will repeat being reset for several times, but what i want is to reset only one time at the posedge of rst signal. do you have any idea of suggestion?

Comment: What do you mean by "repeat being reset for several times", do you mean to say for several clock cycles? 
It does not reset several times, but it stays in that state unless you de-assert the reset signal. That's how it works.

Answer (score 1):

The very first code snippet which you call "high level async reset" logic is "posedge asynchronous reset logic".

The code snippet specified a active high asynchronous reset signal `rst`. "active high" + "asynchronous" means signals generated by this `always` block are reset immediately when `rst` asserts.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you include "posedge/negedge reset" in the sensitivy list, and the reset condition inside the always block has priority over the rest of the sequential logic, it is asynchronous:

```
always @ (posedge clk_i, posedge arst_i) begin
  if(arst_i) begin
    ...this condition has to be first
  end
  else begin
    ...normal sequential logic
  end
end
```

Use "posedge" for active-high reset, and "negedge" for active-low reset.

*Extra note: Sometimes it is also useful to have a reset synchronizer. This synchronized "soft reset" should be included in the normal sequential logic and it would help to have everything synchronized with the clock. By doing this you would have a first asynchronous reset condition, and the last synchronized reset would avoid any metastabiliy problems regarding the asynchronous condition.*

Comment: thanks，what i want to achieve is reset my logic immediately after posedge of rst coming. But not reset my logic at the next posedge of clk.
the code you showed will lead to the occasion that : if my rst signal keep high for a long time, my logic will reset more than once.
do you have some advice?

Comment: maybe controlling the reset's logic, disabling itself in the next clock cycle, I don't think this is a safe way to do it, it can lead to metastability issues, imagine the asynchronous reset is set very close to the posedge of the clock, if you want to try, maybe: always @ (posedge clk) begin if(async_reset) disable_rst <= 1; else disable_rst <= 0; end assign controlled_reset = async_reset & ~disable_rst; //..this would be your reset, it will disable in the next clock cycle

Comment: thanks for your advice. You are right. I finally decided to replace my logic with synchronous reset (and disabled reset input signal at the 2nd clk edge) which can safely achieve the goal of my project. I've learned a lot.